# Need to get in -casesensitive profile name in path annotation

Tags: rest, path, annotations

I'm trying to get the profile info using names. Here "name" is variable which gets any name in the URL. In that case, we not sure about the value in the path annotation. What can be suggested for this case?

```
@GET        
@Path("/{name}") 

public Profile getProfile(@PathParam("name")String name)        {
        return ps.getProfile(name); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please attach another property to profile called 'slug' which is a lowercase of the name and have spaces replaced with dash. For example

if `profile.name = "John"` then `profile.slug ="john"`. 
If `profile.name ="John ok"` then `profile.slug = "john-ok"`

You will have to generate 'slug' using the profile name when saving a new profile.

Your code will then look like this

```
GET        
@Path("/{slug}") 

 public Profile getProfile(@PathParam("slug")String slug)        {
      return ps.getProfile(slug); 
}
```

You could also make use of id generated with uuid.